# xterm Ctrl+Meta keybinding not working

Tags: key-bindings, xterm

I'm trying to custom keybind <kbd>Ctrl+Meta+i</kbd> and it does not seem to work.

Here is what I have in my `.Xresources` file:

```
XTerm.VT100.Translations: #override \
Ctrl      <KeyPress> I: string("^[JDI")  \n\
Meta      <KeyPress> I: string("^[JDMI") \n\
Ctrl Meta <KeyPress> I: string("^[JDCMI")
```

When I run the `showkey -a` command in the terminal to look at what each individual key sequence is generating it spits out: (for <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd> <kbd>Meta+i</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Meta+i</kbd> respectively):

```
^[JDI    27 0033 0x1b
         74 0112 0x4a
         68 0104 0x44
         73 0111 0x49
^[JDMI   27 0333 0x1b
         74 0112 0x4a
         77 0115 0x4d
         73 0111 0x49
^[JDI    27 0033 0x1b
         74 0112 0x4a
         68 0104 0x44
         73 0111 0x49
```

As you can see pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Meta+i</kbd> spits out the sequence <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd>.

It's like the terminal is completely ignoring the fact that I'm holding down both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd> at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this works but the answer is to simply place <kbd>Ctrl+Meta</kbd> definition before all the others like so:

```
XTerm.VT100.Translations: #override \
Ctrl Meta <KeyPress> I: string("^[JDCMI") \n\
Ctrl      <KeyPress> I: string("^[JDI")   \n\
Meta      <KeyPress> I: string("^[JDMI")
```